# Java stack size does not return the number of items in the stack

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, size

I am new to data structures and programming in general, and im learning the concept of a stack by implementing a string reverser. As i wanted to use the stack size as a counter to pop all the items in the stack, i notice that the stack size does not return the number of items in the stack. Example:

```
    public String reverse(String string) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    //Use a stack to reverse this string.As a stack is a LIFO collection, it goes by last in first out.
   
    Stack<Character> characters = new Stack<>();
    char[] characterArray = string.toCharArray();
    for(char ch : characterArray) {
        characters.push(ch);
    }
    for(int i=0; i < characterArray.length; i++) {
        stringBuffer.append(characters.pop());
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
  

}
```

input " helloworldz" returns "zdlrowolleh" as expected. But when using the stack size as a counter....

```
    public String reverse(String string) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    Stack<Character> characters = new Stack<>();
    char[] characterArray = string.toCharArray();
    for(char ch : characterArray) {
        characters.push(ch);
    }
    for(int i=0; i < characters.size(); i++) {
        stringBuffer.append(characters.pop());
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();

}
```

it returns "zdlrow",

meaning that the stack size did not return the number of items in the stack.
Am i missing anything important? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The size of the stack is decreased by `1` with every `pop` operation on it and therefore in the following code block,

```
for(int i=0; i < characters.size(); i++) {
    stringBuffer.append(characters.pop());
}
```

the loop will be executed for only the half number of times as compared to that in the following code block

```
for(int i=0; i < characterArray.length; i++) {
    stringBuffer.append(characters.pop());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do a loop conditioned on information from the `characters` stack itself, the proper choice would be:

```
    while (!characters.isEmpty()) {
        stringBuffer.append(characters.pop());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Java provides the Iterator interface for iterate through complex data structures like stack, map and lists.
you might have to refactor your code to use the iterator interface.

```
Iterator<Character> iterator = stack.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
sb.append(stack.pop());
}
```